# Can we connect to a computer on the same private network using MAC address?

Tags: java, c, networking, private-network

I could connect two computers withing a private network using private IP addresses using socket programming. Is it possible to do the same using MAC addresses?

If it is possible, any example on Java/C/C++ would be appreciated. I couldn't find any helpful posts on the web regarding the same.

**UPDATE:**

I was curios to know if it's possible to connect to another computer on the same private network just by knowing the MAC address? One logic behind the question could be the IP address assigned to a network device can be different everytime the router is rebooted. So, MAC address sounds more solid option to have for identity in this case.

(Though I am aware MAC address can be changed too.)

Comment: You need IP addresses in order to make socket programming work, maybe can you give more details about what you want to do?

Comment: I was just curious if we can connect to another computer just by knowing MAC address. Like, IP Address can change for a particular device on network on every reboot of the router.

Comment: There are protocols which only use MAC addresses, but they only work on the LAN (they cannot be routed to another LAN). Because of the limitation of only working on a single LAN, they have fallen by the wayside, especially after the Internet was commercialized in 1995.

Comment: What do you mean by _connect_: literally `connect(2)` or just to send and receive data?

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for reminding. :D

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAC addresses are used to identify "physical" entities in a network.

Whereas sockets exist on the IP layer.

MAC addresses denote hardware objects; if you want those objects to communicate, you need to look into the layers above of that. And either you use existing protocols; such as UDP/TCP; or you would have to define your complete own protocol.

In other words: the one and only function of a MAC address is to identify a unique hardware component within the "scope" of the visible network. The MAC address doesn't define any service/protocol that could be used to connect one MAC address endpoint to another one.

So, in short the answer is: no it is not passable.

Comment: See my Update, although you might not like my answer.

Comment: You said this earlier. "And either you use existing protocols; such as UDP/TCP." And then your update says "It's not possible." I am confused. Did I miss anything?

Comment: It is not possible without further work on your side!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  IP is one possible layer 2 protocol, but you can run your own protocol on top of ethernet.  FCoE, for example, bypasses TCP-IP and runs its own protocol. Since Fibre Channel can support network traffic as well as storage traffic you could theoretically connect up your network using FCoE.  With a little programming effort you could add a socket layer.

Comment: So, you are saying it's not possible with existing protocols? I will have to implement my own?

Comment: @DilipRajBaral Surprisingly he is telling you exactly the same as I did. MAC addresses define an addressing scheme, not a communication protocol.